# Qt, Color Picker Dialog?

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a color picker dialog for Qt like the following?

Also it needs to have a OnColorChanged signal which is called when ever the selected color changes. I want to give a live preview when they are changing the colors, that is why.

[image: http://i49.tinypic.com/vpu7hv.jpg]

Using google I could only find this one that was a triangle in side of a circle and personally I think it looks ugly.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[QColorDialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcolordialog.html) does exactly what you want.

(It is easy to find when you Ctrl-F through the [list of Qt classes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/classes.html) for "color")

Comment: Updated link for `QColorDialog`: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcolordialog.html
When the review queue is not that long someone might update it (also a reminder for myself to try it later)

Answer (score 0):

Qt has now a "normal" color picker: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolordialog.html#details