# Qt gridview - one element take more place

Tags: c++, qt

My window have got grid layout. In Grid layout I have got tabwidget.

In first tab, I have got grid layout -> groupbox -> vertical layout -> items, and vertical layout -> groupbox -> gridlayout and items.

And in tabwidget -> first tab -> verticallayout -> groupbox -> gridlayout -> QTableWidget and push button.

I want to give this `QTableWidget` more space (in height) than have second layout in this tab.

This table must be readable, second layout is less important so it can be smaller than first layout.

But when resizing proportions must be preserved.

So how to make that verticallayout take 70% of place, not 50%?

Comment: Ask about *Do you know about `QColorPicker` in Qt (Link in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22643693) is expired)* in another separate question.

Comment: I saw that it is possible to set minimum size, for my tab, but when i resize window - second widget take the same amount of space as first widget ... and finally size of first and second widget is 50%/50%